# CGAffineTransform - CGPoint within a CGRect

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I need to recalculate the coordinates of a point within a rectangle when a specific `CGAffineTransform` is applied to the rectangle. The transform is basically a device rotation, and while that limits me to only 3 possibilities (+ the original unrotated position), I wonder if there is a way to perform this dynamically without having to use `switch` for the 4 possible positions. `CGPointApplyAffineTransform` does not do what I need in this case.

The diagram illustrates the desired effect. On the left is the unrotated device in its default portrait orientation. On the right it is rotated counterclockwise, and the new (x, y) coordinates would be given by (oldWidth - oldY, oldX). For other rotations it would be different. Is there a way to do this without switching over all possible rotations?

[image: example rotation effect]